# Convert Java Project into Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have a Java Project inside eclipse that contains a liste of an external jars and i would like to export this project as an eclipse plugin , i tried a lot of solution but i either have this error :

---

The type javax.persistence.CascadeType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

---

or i get another error that telling me that he do not recongnise any of external jars

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's actually a Java project, first you need to actually convert it to an Eclipse plug-in project ("Configure > Convert to plugin project" in context menu for your project). Then follow advice in http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html to fix dependency problem.

Answer (score 1):

OSGi bundles (eclipse plugins are bundles) can only see their own code and other bundles.  They can't see random 3rd party jars unless they're included (license permitting) within that bundle, or the 3rd party jars are turned into OSGi bundles themselves (the preferred method).

"i tried a lot of solution" doesn't help.  Please update your question with the configuration you started with and 1 or 2 solutions (complete steps) you've already tried, like the MANIFEST.MF files that they generated, etc